# How construct a suggestion?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions, ellipsis, coordination, imperative-sentences

I want to use a sentence-suggestion, but I am confused how to (or how not to) use pronouns.
Example:

> (*If you*) Share on facebook, and (*you will*) get free a something!

This will be used in an advertisement as a single sentence.

Comment: The pronouns would be implied here so you don't explicitly have to mention them. The "you" is understood to be present. *Share on facebook to win a free <mention goodie here>!*

Comment: To add to MamtaD's comment, the only real problem with your sentence is "get free a something". We'd say "get a free something", using "free" as an adjective rather than an adverb. The adverbal form only really appears with the word "for": "get a something for free!"But "get a free something" is the best of all of these. MamtaD's "win" instead of "get" is also good throughout.

Comment: Perhaps omit "**a**" altogether: "... ***and get something free***".